# Are Newfoundland's and Quebec's power grid synchronized

Tags: synchronization, hvdc

By the Maritime Link project (HVDC), which finished this year, Newfoundland is linked asynchronously to Nova Scotia, which is part of the Eastern Interconnection.

But is the power grid of Newfoundland and Labrador [synchronized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(alternating_current)) with the [Hydro-Quebec network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydro-Qu%C3%A9bec%27s_electricity_transmission_system)?

Comment: If the asynchronous link is the only link between the two areas, then the areas are not synchronized.

Comment: I don't speak English by nature, so to which department belongs my question?

Comment: It belongs here. many participants are electronics engineers and some of them forget that electrical engineering questions are also accepted here. *We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics,* https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

No, the Quebec's grid is isolated from the rest of the North American continent.  This is due to the historical decision to make sure that Quebec is 100% independent in terms of energy production. This also mean that Quebec is capable  of rebuilding its network in case of a total black-out because Hydro-Quebec regulate the voltage of its grid and the frequency.

The only interconnection between Newfoundland and Labrador and Quebec is the DC interconnection for Churchills Falls dam.

Comment: So Quebec is akin to Texas in that regard? That's rather interesting.

Comment: The eastern interconnection in North America is a very large synchronous system. As we saw in the 2003 blackout, Hydro-Quebec was electrically isolated from the issue. They were also able to provide power to some places during the black out. Staying electrically isolated has benefits for the overall North American system in terms of reliability.

Comment: Even though they are electrically isolated, Hydro Quebec still purchases approximately 3.0 GW per year from Newfoundland and Labrador (http://www.hydroquebec.com/sustainable-development/energy-environment/power-generation-purchases-exports.html). Their allocated capacity from Churchill Falls (Labrador) Corporation Limited power station is 5.4GW per year until 2041 (http://www.hydroquebec.com/generation/autres-sources.html).

Comment: @BrittKelly Yes, Hydro-Quebec help with the Churchill Falls dam. In exchange, HQ can buy the production at the price of 3 tenth of a cents per kw produced.

Comment: @esilk Yes, Texas is the same situation as quebec. The main challenges with grid like Texas or Quebec is the control of frequency. Because you don't have as much power install as let say the eastern interconnection, frequency can swing much more in these smaller grids.